# Error: Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/lib/tools.jar

Tags: maven, ant, java, jasperserver

I am trying to build jasperserver on linux. It uses ant and maven. While executing the ant command it gives this exception. I checked on the same path however the lib folder is not there at the same path. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you have installed a JDK? A mere JRE does not contain tools.jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: Failed to resolve dependency: tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860350), [Unable to locate tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815), [Unable to locate tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676107), [Ant error when trying to build file, can't find tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618281), [Ant + Vista 64 : “Unable to locate tools.jar”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378535).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tools.jar is present only in jdk, not jre.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue by installing jdk..

Thanks to all for reply ..

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same message running Ant after a JVM update. I fixed it by setting JAVA_HOME to JDK.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your eclipse is defaulting to your 32bit version of your jre. If you do everything right with JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin and your running a 32bit version of eclipse you'll end up using something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin.

once you fix your jdk issue You will need to pass it on the end of a shortcut -vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin"

Or fix your JAVA_HOME

Other suggestions have been to make sure your eclipse is using the jdk not jre http://gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/15/Telling-Eclipse-to-use-the-JDK-instead-of-JRE.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just for others reference:By default eclipse will point to jre not jdk. if you want to change default jre please got to
       **window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs**
      click on **add** button select **Standanrd VM** then set JRE home.
here you can provide your installed jdk path it will look like below in case of windows. 
  **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101**